# Cannot stream simple string in Play 2.5 (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, streaming, akka, akka-stream

I'm really struggling to stream a simple string in **Play 2.5**. So if I wanted to output the string "Hello" I might start with this:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source


class Enum @Inject() extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok.chunked(Source("hello"))
  }
}
```

But clearly this doesn't compile. I have read the [*Play* documentation regarding streaming](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream) and I know that in previous versions `Ok.chunked(Enumerator("hello"))` would have been the way. And unfortunately [Play's migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/StreamsMigration25#streams-migration-guide) hasn't clarified any of this to me. Maybe I've been looking too long at this screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Source("hello")` is a source of `Char`, because `Source()` takes a `Seq`.

Since `Char` are not `Writeable` (in the sense of `play.api.http.Writeable`), you cannot give a source of `Char` to `Ok.chunked`

If you want to send just one `String` element, you should do `Source.single("hello")`

Comment: Really simple concise answer - probably really obvious but sometimes you just can't see it. Thanks!